# Layout manger for swing JComponents representing calendar events

Tags: java, swing, calendar, layout-manager

I am working on a java app in which I need to layout JComponents representing calendar events, in a container:

[image]

I use custom layout manager, and I doubt if is the right solution. I calculate the top x position and the height, based on the event start and end time. 
I also calculate the number of overlapping events for each event, and as a result the max number of overlaps (which represents the max number of columns).

When it comes to calculating y position and width of each component, it gets complicated because of many overlapping possibilities.

**My question:** is there an available layout manager which can help me optimize such layout ? or should I continue the using and improving the custom layout manager ?

Comment: Perhaps MigLayout or GroupLayout could do this. Or failing that, a custom manager as you're doing.

Comment: Thanks, I read about a few others and did not find a good one that can be used or extended to do what I need. I will dig into Mig anf Group. I wonder if they have an option to layout one axis (say y) only.

Comment: The GroupLayout is very flexible, but was mainly written to be generated by computer/IDE and not very coder-friendly. MigLayout is supposed to be flexible and powerful, but is a 3rd party layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After exploring various layout managers, it became clear to me the most significant part of the work that needs to be done, is calculation the constrains.

I used the following approach:

For each container representing a day :

- calculated the Y position (vertical) and height of each JComponent  (representing a single calendar event) based on the time scale.
- To calculate X position and width of each JComponent, I had to analyze overlapping  components and find which “sub column” (or sub column**s**)  each should occupy.
- Iterated over all container’s JComponents (sorted by height, representing duration), checking each against all others for time overlapping JComponents. Doing so I was able to calculate the number of required sub-columns, and the appropriate sub-column (X position) for each JComponent.
- Based on the X position of each JComponent I was able to calculate its width, by searching the next overlapping  JComponent  (if any). The X position of this next overlapping JComponent limits the width.

After having all the needed constrains, I could use a simply layout manager (like Formlayout), but I did not see the value of doing so. Setting bounds for each JComponent was straight forward.

[image]