# Layout calendar events

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtable

In my Java Swing application, I have a JTable do display the weekdays and the time in 30min intervals. I now want to be able to add entries into my JTable.

[image: The table, red entry is edited in.]

I thought about doing it with a JList, but I wouldn't know how to get it to work. The red thing in the image is supposed to show how I want the final thing to look like. Anyone got an idea?

Comment: You've asked two different questions.  You can make a JTable editable, so users can enter their schedule.  If you want to show allocated times with colored bars, then you'd have to draw an image of the schedule.

Comment: Using `JTable` or `JList` means that you do not allow [overlapping events](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32153204/3992939)?

Comment: @c0der the JList is no necessity, but just an example of what I have thought of. The link you posted shows exactly what I want in the end.

Comment: You many want to [edit] your question to add any essential info. You can follow the explanation in the answer I linked. For more help post  [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) or [mre] including hard-coded test data.