# JLayeredPane disrupting Layout

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, miglayout, jlayeredpane

I want to have a calendar with entries overlapping a JTable. 
That JTable is inside a scrollpane which again is inside a JLayeredPane.

```
setLayout(new MigLayout("", "[:20%:200px,grow][26%,grow][26%,grow][26%]", "[:15%:80px,grow][85%,grow]"));

add(layeredPane, "cell 1 1 3 1,grow");
layeredPane.setLayout(new MigLayout("", "[100%,grow]", "[100%,grow]"));
layeredPane.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

table = new JTable();

JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
layeredPane.add(scrollPane, "cell 0 0,grow",0);
```

I'm now calculating the bounds for my panel which is supposed to be an entry. When adding that entry to the JLayeredPane however, the whole layout is disrupted and it seems to be on the same layer. Even if my calculated values are wrong, that wrong result is still supposed to show up on a different layer.

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setBounds((int)position.getX(), (int)position.getY(), width, height);
panel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
pane.add(panel, 300); // This is the JLayeredPane
```

When I go into fullscreen however, this happens:

[image]

Why is the pane not showing the panel on a different layer and why is my layout corrupted by it?

Comment: In your last question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61564904/layout-calendar-events you were asked to post an [mre]. An MRE should be posted with every question. That is you post your code with a JFrame, layered pane, JTable and the panel. You should NOT use the MigLayout, since that is not part of the JDK. The point is to learn how to use the layered pane first before worrying about your application.

Answer (score 1):

```
pane.add(panel, 300);
```

Well, that appears to be the code where you add your panel to the layered pane. Although elsewhere in your code you also have a variable called "layeredPane", so I'm not sure.

If that is referring to the layered pane then that is not how you add a component to the layer:

1. why would you use 300 for the layer?  that is not a pixel location
2. The layer is specified by an `Integer` value, not an int.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Layered Panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html) for more information and a working example.